# In Repository, how to replace deprecated load() function?

Tags: magento2, factory, service-contract, repository

I know we should use **service contracts(Repository)** over `$model->load()`, but **in Repository itself**, how to replace the deprecated `load()` function?

For example, in `Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository`, the official Magento 2.1.9 used the **deprecated** `load()` function **too**.

```
public function getById($pageId)
{
    $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
    $page->load($pageId);
    if (!$page->getId()) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('CMS Page with id "%1" does not exist.', $pageId));
    }
    return $page;
}
```

### Reference

[When Should We Use a Repository and Factory in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2)

[Is there ever a reason to prefer $model->load() over service contracts?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111286/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-prefer-model-load-over-service-contracts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **ResourceModel**'s load() instead, which extends 
`Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager`'s load() method.

We could see a example in: `Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository`

```
public function getById($blockId)
    {
        $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
        $this->resource->load($block, $blockId);
        if (!$block->getId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('CMS Block with id "%1" does not exist.', $blockId));
        }
        return $block;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, accept and my vote ran out today. repositoryModel? It should be ResourceModel, right?

Comment: **ResourceModel**'s load() which extends `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager`'s load() method

Comment: yeah, that was my bad. can say a typo :)