# Correct way to save entries to database

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model, crud

I want to know, what is the correct way to implement CRUD operations in **Magento 2**?

because I found a lot of examples but they use deprecated methods.

I created a table ('quote reserved item') with some.
id (PK)
quote_id FK on entity_id form quote table.
product_id.

I want to save update and read information from this table. So i created the following classes :

[image]

1. Api\ReservedItemRepositoryInterface.php that has a method save();
   Api\Data\ReservedItemInterface.php

   Model\ResourceModel\ReservedItem\Collection.php
   Model\ResourceModel\ReservedItem.php Model\ReservedItem.php
   Model\ReservedItemRepository.php here i want to implement that save
   method without using deprecated methods. If that is not possible
   which method should i use.

   class ReservedItemRepository implements ReservedItemRepositoryInterface{

   ```
   protected $collectionFactory;

   protected $reservedItemFactory;

   public function __construct(
       CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
       ReservedItemFactory $reservedItemFactory
   )
   {
       $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       $this->reservedItemFactory = $reservedItemFactory;
   }

   /**
    * @param ReservedItemInterface $reservedItem
    * @return ReservedItemInterface
    */
   public function save(ReservedItemInterface $reservedItem, $saveOptions = false)
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: Can you give any more specifics and context? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111286/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-prefer-model-load-over-service-contracts

Comment: @RyanHoerr is my question a bit clearer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your class look like this:

```
class ReservedItemRepository implements ReservedItemRepositoryInterface{

    protected $collectionFactory;

    protected $reservedItemFactory;
    protected $reservedItemResourceModel;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ReservedItemFactory $reservedItemFactory,
        ReservedItem $reservedItemResourceModel //this should be an instance the ResourceModel\ReserverItem class
    )
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->reservedItemFactory = $reservedItemFactory;
        $this->reservedItemResourceModel = $reservedItemResourceModel;
    }

    /**
     * @param ReservedItemInterface $reservedItem
     * @return ReservedItemInterface
     */
    public function save(ReservedItemInterface $reservedItem, $saveOptions = false)
    {
        $this->reservedItemResourceModel->save($reservedItem);
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. Use the resource model `save` method for saving.

Comment: Yap this worked without any deprecated methods. Thanks guys

Comment: @Marius Please share an example to show how do you use this code. How do you add new record to database?

Comment: @SukhdevsinhZala. I did share the code. You can  call this where you want to use it.

Comment: @Marius sorry for interrupting, How can i call this repository method in an observer to save some customer data to a custom table? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You are suppose to instantiate model that maps to the table that you want up update. And use it's setData() method. Once all data is populated. use save() method which will in tern will write values into database.

Answer (score 0):

you could use pestle https://github.com/astorm/pestle

```
pestle.phar generate_crud_model Yourvendor_Yourmodule Yourmodelname
```

this will create the model, the resource model, the model repository, table schema(basic one) and the api interface ;)