# How to add an extension attribute into "Customer Address"

Tags: magento-2.1, di

I want to manage the "extension attribute" named "example" into "Customer Address" entity.

I've created a new custom module, and I've added the extension attribute into `etc/extension_attribute.xml` configuration file:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <attribute code="example" type="boolean" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Then, I've deleted the cache and run the `magento setup:di:compile` command in order to recreate the Dependency Injection cache files.
I could see them in the `var/generation` folder:

> ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtension.php:
>   public function getExample()
>   ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtension.php:
>   * @param boolean $example   ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtension.php:
>   public function setExample($example)
>   ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtension.php:
>   $this->setData('example', $example);
>   ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtensionInterface.php:
>   public function getExample();
>   ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtensionInterface.php:
>   * @param boolean $example ./var/generation/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtensionInterface.php:
>   public function setExample($example);

Now... I want to intercept `\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface::getById()` (after) action.
I've added a new plugin into `etc/di.xml` configuration file:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository">
    <plugin name="your_plugin_name"
            type="your_name\module_name\Plugin\CustomerAddressRepository"
            sortOrder="1000" />
</type>
```

and I've created the related plugin:

```
class CustomerAddressRepository
{
    public function afterGetById(
        $subject,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address $result
    ) {
        // my code...
    }
}
```

but when I try to get the new extension attribute `example`, the `$result->getExtensionAttributes()` function always returns a `null` value.

I've already implemented extension attributes into the `Magento_Checkout` module with success.
I've already read similar question like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90766/transferring-a-bespoke-customer-address-attribute-to-the-customer-address-data-l).
but I haven't found any solution to my problem.

Have I forgotten an implementation step?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess:

You could try to plug in after to `\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface::getById()`

and as far as I know, `$result->getExtensionAttributes()` may return null - If it does, just take a `\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory`
and then use `$this->extAttribFactory->create();`